# Trying to access a value pair which is in a dictionary inside a list of dictionaries and that list is inside a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, binance-api-client

I have a function gathering some binance API data

```
from binance.client import Client
client = Client(apikey, apisecret)

d = client.get_symbol_info(symbol)

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'symbol': 'VGXUSDT', 'status': 'TRADING', 'filters': [{'filterType': 'PRICE_FILTER', 'minPrice': '0.00100000'}, {'filterType': 'LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.10000000', 'maxQty': '92141578.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.10000000'}]}
```

I am trying to access the stepSize value and return it as a float.

I have tried loops, list comprehension, and list comprehension inside a loop.

Comment: if your dictionary was named `d` you could try `float(d['filters'][1]['stepSize'])
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is dictionary inside of array inside of dictionary (JSON response). So to access you need to use keys:

```
def precision(symbol)

    info = client.get_symbol_info(symbol)
    return float(info['filters'][1]['stepSize'])
```